# Ajax jquery C# .net JSON passing params into [webmethod] from javascript - internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf

the javascript to pass params:

```
<script>    
    var str = "pears"
    $.ajax({
        url: 'WebService.asmx/HelloWorld', //'/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld',
        data: "{outputtype:'" + str + "'}",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            var response = msg.d;
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error + "\n" + xhr + "\n" + status); //do something if there is an error
        }
    });
```

and the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(String str)
{
    return str;
}
```

I've spent an entire day on this and tried out countless variations of passing params into this method but none work. I've tried on different machines and I've tried making the webmethod static and I've tried various ways of passing in the values from the javascript.

It will however work if I DON'T pass params.

Comment: The WebMethod accepts a param named "str", you are passing "outputtype"... the param names must match for the above to work :)

Comment: as @Pranay said you should define the method as **static** and the data name in the ajax call must be same as the argument of the webmethod and it is **case-sensitive**.  
 
also read the Workaround section at this url: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

**problem with this  parameter name , change parameter name in your method**

```
[WebMethod] public static string HelloWorld(String outputtype)
                           { return outputtype; }
```

and also make method static, update code is above

Comment: You may want to change the `return str` as well... ? :)

Comment: Hi Pranay and Tallmaris thanks for your speedy response, I didn't realize the the parsm names needed to match, but even so I still get the same error:--
[11:48:08.459] POST http://localhost:40029/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 15ms]

Comment: Try to change your data param in ajax request like so: `data: "{ 'outputtype' :'" + str + "'}"`

Comment: @user1809104 : did you uncomment this `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this site, it will useful for you..

```
var str = "pears"
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
         data: "{'strabc1': '1'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: true,
         cache: false,
         success: function (data) {                       
             alert(data.d);
             alert(data.d[0]);                 
         }
      })
```

**Server Side Method**

If you want return collection from server side method, the given below *ArrayList* return method will be useful..,

```
[WebMethod]
public static ArrayList HelloWorld(string strabc1)
{
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.Add("abc");
        arr.Add("123");
        arr.Add("fff");
        return arr;
 }
```

[refer this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys but if I had tried that site I would have got the same error and if I had tried that code the same as the webmethod was static - for some reason when I remove the static keyword it works fine, after I match up the param names of course. 

Does anyone know why this happens? if the webmethod is static it doesn't work.